# XPages File Download Control: NotesException "Object has been removed or recycled"

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have troubles with the XPages `xp:fileDownload` core control, running on a `Domino 9.0.1 FP3` server. On a `Domino 8.5.3 FP6` server I have no problems, it works perfect!

*Here's the simple source code of the xpage:*

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" computeWithForm="onsave" 
            formName="Files" action="editDocument"
            documentId="6E004D63CD737B79C1257E520050C14C">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1" value="#{document1.Body}"></xp:fileUpload>

    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="fileDownload1" displayLastModified="false" 
        value="#{document1.Body}" allowDelete="true">
    </xp:fileDownload>

    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button value="Save" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

*Take a look at the following scenario:*

---

1. Upload some files (using `xp:fileUpload` core control)

[image]

2. Delete a file and save the document (repeat this step)

[image]

3. After some repeats, I get the following notes exception

[image]

Remember: I have no troubles on `Domino Server 8.5.3 FP6`!

Comment: I just ran this on a Domino 9.0.1 FP3 dev server after adapting the Form name to one I already had. It ran without issue. I would recommend either: 1- check and/or clear your querySave code from the Form or 2- try removing your _computeWithForm="onsave"_ property. This should help with your trouble shooting.

Comment: @EricMcCormick: It makes no difference removing _computWithForm_, furthermore I have no code inside _querySave_

Comment: Same issue in Domino 9.0.1 FP6.
Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

This may be caused by XPage persistence settings. The component tree is stored in memory / on disk and there are a maximum number of entries, set in XSP Properties. The amount of uploads / deletes may be meaning the original component tree is no longer available.

Check the persistence settings in the application / server. If this is the cause it will consistently fail after *x* refreshes on the same page.

One option is increasing. Alternatively, in 9.0.1 the file upload can be changed to run via a partial refresh, which may also resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried both of your suggestions (partial refresh and different persistence settings), but it doesn't make any change. I still have the same troubles